# Proving that $T^{-1}(V)$ is a subspace of $X$ when $V$ is a subspace of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just came across a question which is as follows:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $ T : X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator with domain $D(T) \subset X$ and range $R(T) \subset Y$.

The first part of the question asks us to show that $T^{-1}$ is linear as well, which I have been able to do.

However I'm confused with the second part. It says:

Let $V$ be a subspace of $X$ and $W$ be a subspace of $Y$. Show that $T^{-1}(V)$ is a subspace of $X$ and $T^{-1}(W)$ is a subspace of $Y$.

I simply don't understand how $T^{-1}(V)$ can be a subspace of $X$. Shouldn't it have been:

Show that $T^{-1}(W)$ is a subspace of  $X$ and $T(V)$ is a subspace of $Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I agree with your diagnosis. The notation $T^{-1}(V)$ isn't justified since $V$ is not necessarily in the range of $T$. It's much more likely that $T(V)$ and $T^{-1}(W)$ were meant.

By the way you mentioned you were able to show "$T^{-1}$ is linear." Whenever $T$ isn't one to one, it isn't even a homomorphism, so it will often fail to be linear. When it's 1-1 though it can be regarded as a homomorphism from a subspace of $Y$ to a subspace of $X$, yes.

One good thing to keep in mind here is that $T^{-1}(W):=\{v\in D(T)\mid T(v)\in W\}$ is defined even if $T^{-1}$ isn't a function.

Comment: Yes I thought so too because $T^{-1}$ is defined from $Y$ to $X$ so it just did not make sense to me! Thanks @rschwieb...

Comment: @BhavishSuarez Added a bit to my solution after you commented. Just letting you know.

Comment: I let $y_1$, $y_2$ $\in$ $R(T)$, then $y_1=T(x_1)$ for some $x_1\;\in D(T)$ and $y_2 = T(x_2)$ for some $x_2 \in D(T)$ and then I used the property of $T^{-1}T=I_{D(T)}$ to show that $T^{-1}$ is linear.

Comment: @BhavishSuarez No, you are making a grave mistake. The *function* $T^{-1}$ exists only if $T$ is one-to-one. The *set* $T^{-1}(W)$ is always defined whether $T^{-1}$ is defined or not. If $T(x)=T(y)=z$ for $x\neq y$, then an inverse function would have to map $z$ to *both* $x$ and $y$, which is impossible for a function. $T\circ T^{-1}=I$ only if $T^{-1}$ exists, but if it doesn't exist, you are out of luck.

Comment: In this case, how do we go about proving that $T^{-1}$ is linear?

Comment: @BhavishSuarez We don't: why would we spend time proving a property of something that doesn't exist? I guess the question was poorly worded. It makes sense to prove that $T^{-1}(W)$ is a *linear subspace*, but proving anything about "$T^{-1}$" at all is a waste of time until you know that $T$ is one-to-one.